# Area income data for percentiles other than the median?

Tags: usa, us-census, economics, income

I'm looking for data similar to the Area Median Income, except that provides information about other percentiles. For instance, what are the 10th or 90th percentiles of income in my county?

I saw that HUD releases data that calculates "percent of AMI" for various percentages. But 10% of the median isn't the same as the income of those living in the 5th percentile.

Any leads?

Comment: hi, not counties but with `public use microdata areas` you can calculate this yourself off of the microdata using http://asdfree.com/american-community-survey-acs.html by changing `svyquantile` to `0.05` or `0.1` or `0.9` instead of `0.50`